# Clip the BBOX coordinates

Tags: openlayers, wms, extents

Is there any control on BBOX to clip the coordinates before sending request to the GeoServer.

The allowed coordinates are [-90, 90, -180,180]. The issue is when ZoomIN/out the BBox calculating the boundaries and sending the request to Geoserver, but when the coordiates are not falling in the allowed range the DB(Mongo) is throwing error.

Ideally, this should be solved at MongoDB plubin but seems the defect is not at fixed.

Looking for an option to do this at openlayers by clipping the coordinates if it falling above or below in the allowed range. So, if we get the control on bbox while page load,zoomin, zoomout and panning then we can do something.

```
 this.wmsSource = new ImageWMS({
      url: 'http://localhost/geoserver/mongoworkspace/wms',
      params:
      {
        'LAYERS': 'mongoworkspace:sample11',
        'FORMAT': 'image/png8',
        'TILED': false
      },
      serverType: 'geoserver',
      visible: true
    });

  this.wmsLayer = new ImageLayer({
      source: this.wmsSource
      //extent: [-90, -180, 90, 180],
    });

    this.projection = new Projection({
      code: 'EPSG:4326',
      units: 'degrees',
      axisOrientation: 'neu'
    });

    this.view = new OlView({
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 1,
      extent: [-90, -180, 90, 180],
      projection: this.projection
    });

    this.map = new Map({
      layers: [
        this.wmsLayer
      ],
      target: 'map',
      view: this.view
    });
```

Comment: One possible solution would be to specify extent for your layer.

Comment: I have mentioned this in view "(  OlView({ extent: [-179, -89, 179, 89] }) )" but still the request is going like the below

** http://localhost/geoserver/mongoworkspace/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng8&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=mongoworkspace%3Asample11&TILED=false&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&STYLES=&WIDTH=1454&HEIGHT=728&BBOX=-255.9375%2C-511.171875%2C255.9375%2C511.171875 **

Comment: Add all the relevant code to your question. Without seeing how you construct your WMS requests it's all just guessing.

Comment: Have updated the code in question section

Comment: It looks like you already tried setting extent on layer. It didn't help?

Comment: It didn't help. We observed that it's not at all considering the values specified in the extent.

Comment: Try definig projection with desired extent and setting it on source.

Comment: Tried as suggested by defining extent in projection but still seeing the same issue.

Comment: As extent seems to be not working, can we get control on BBOX to update the boundaries before sending the request.

Comment: Unlike WFS (see example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-wfs.html) there seems to be no way to programmatically set `bbox` for WMS.

Comment: For a WMS GetMap request BBOX is a required parameter. OL will work out the parameter based on the area of view.